# Laravel - Setting auth user inside controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

Is it bad practice for me to set the auth user inside my base controller as follows:

```
 abstract class Controller extends BaseController
 {
      use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

      protected $user;

      public function __construct()
      {

           $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

                 $this->user = Auth::user();

                 view()->share('signedIn', Auth::check());
                 view()->share('user', $this->user);

                  return $next($request);
           });

      }
  }
```

Or should I be accessing the auth user inside my controller methods as follows:

```
 public function index()
{
      $user = Auth::user();
}
```

I'm asking based on taylors comments (https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3)

However Jeffery Way seems to be setting this in the constructor as demonstrated in a number of lessons on Laracast?

Comment: It is very common to [call some middleware in constructor of controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#controller-middleware). I would say Jeffrey set whole middleware code there in fave of quicker showing the lesson. Go with docs dedicated middleware and call it in constructor and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Tpojka I'm aware it's common to call middleware in constructor of controller, my question is related to resolving the authenticated user in constructor which according to Taylor is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions, you can't work with session inside controller constructor as you could in 5.2. You're just watching old lessons.

Also, define middleware in its own class, not in a controller.

Comment: the docs advise to use a closure based middleware which makes sense if you want to set a property on the controller.

Comment: @adam78 docs do not advise this. You can do a lot of stuff like validating form input in controllers, working with data and keep business logic etc, but these are the bad practices.

Comment: see the upgrade guide - section on controllers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0